# Making a simple shape move in OpenGL (Shape is in data structures)

Tags: c++, variables, opengl, data-structures

I want to make the body (square) move left when I press the left arrow key. Unfortunately, it's in data structures and I don't know what to put in the `void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y)` part to make it move.

```
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#include "Glut_Setup.h"



**struct Vertex
{
float x,y,z;
};
Vertex Body []=
{
(-0.5, -2, 0),
(0.5, -2, 0),
(0.5, -3, 0),
(-0.5, -3, 0)
};**




void GameScene()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);





glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(-0.5, -2, 0);
glVertex3f(0.5, -2, 0);
glVertex3f(0.5, -3, 0); 
glVertex3f(-0.5, -3, 0);
glEnd();







glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Keys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
switch(key)
{

}
}

**void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
switch(key)
{
}
}**
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is very basic opengl knowledge you can get from practically any book or tutorial site out there. The thing you are looking for is called a Model-View matrix. The idea is that (in fixed-pipeline opengl) you push a matrix onto the matrix stack with which all your vertices are multiplied with. You can then modify this matrix by calls to e.g. glTranslate. See for example this: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/ (but use glTranslate rather than glRotate). A tutorial site for modern opengl is here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: My above comment mentioned an old and a new way to do things in opengl. As you are obviously just starting with opengl, I'd heavily suggest directly going "modern".

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call glTranslatef.

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(delta_x, delta_y, -100.f);
//draw here
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL, there are generally two ways to move an object: glMatrices or direct manipulation of variables.

OpenGL provides the function `glTranslatef()`. If you know about matrices, what this does in 3d space is adding `tx or ty or tz` to their corresponding components in your vector. In OpenGL, this happens behind the scenes so in order to use the `glTranslate` object, you would do the following:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(1.0, 0, 0);

//drawing code

glPopMatrix();
```

Each of the vertices you draw will be multiplied by a matrix to perform transformations.

The second method is to directly manipulate the components of your objects. In order to do this, you need to use variables in your drawing code such as:

```
glVertex3f(vx, vy, vz);
glVertex3f(vx + 1.0, vy - 1.0, vz); // not a real example, just get the idea
```

Then when you want to move the vertex in the positive x axis, you simply add the amount to vx:

```
vx+=0.5;
```

The next time your object is drawn, it will use the new value of vx.

A simple google search can get you the answer for how to respond to key input:
http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node54.html
But anyways, this is an idea on how it works:

```
switch(key)
{
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
vx++;
break;
}
```